# Define javascript variable outside of the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I want to acess a variable that is defined in an asset file.
Currently, my code looks like this:

`<script type="text/javascript"> 
   handler = something;
</script>`

Then I can use "handler" with no problems inside the html. The case is that I want to move this piece of JS to a file inside assets folder, to a cleaner view, assuming that the file is already being loaded by asset pipeline.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `window.handler = something` to set global variable.

Comment: Clear and awesome. Thanks mate.